# How to parse the xml using nsxmlparser with same names of multiple nodes in iphone programming?

Tags: iphone, nsxmlparser

How can I parse using NSXMLParser if I need all the images,

```
<title>Title</title>
<description>my description is here </description>

<images>

<image>http://www.sosmoths.com/mothImages/800px-Tineola.bisselliella.7218.jpg</image>

<image>http://www.sosmoths.com/mothImages/800px-Tineola.bisselliella.mounted.jpg</image>

<image>http://www.sosmoths.com/mothImages/800px-XN_Tineola_bisselliella_1.jpg</image>

<image>http://www.sosmoths.com/mothImages/Tineola_bisselliella.JPG</image>

</images>
```

There are more nodes like title, description, so how to parse such xml, I am confused about image nodes, I am thinking to use NSMutableArray for this, but still not clear to do code?

Comment: http://sosmoths.com/.xml/moths.xml

Comment: This is XML ROM, now what can I do, I want to use NSXMLParser, not touchXML or any else @Ron

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
use this it work

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict{
    NSLog(@"%@",elementName);
    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"moths"]){
        mytblarray=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    } else if([elementName isEqualToString:@"moth"]){
        tmpdic=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    }
    else if([elementName isEqualToString:@"images"]){
        imgArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }

}

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string{

    if(tmpstr!=nil && [tmpstr retainCount]>0){ [tmpstr release]; tmpstr=nil; }
    tmpstr=[[NSString alloc] initWithString:string];

}

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName{

    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"moth"]){
        [mytblarray addObject:tmpdic];
        [tmpdic release];
    }if([elementName isEqualToString:@"images"]){
        [tmpdic setValue:imgArray forKey:elementName];
    }
    else if([elementName isEqualToString:@"image"]){
        [imgArray addObject:tmpstr];        
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanx Ron, I will apply tonight and upvoted and accepted the answer if it will work for me

Comment: I have accepted the answer, but there is one more question, there every title, I have to save the data in their respective controller, so how can I save data of 4 moth in four different objects

Comment: if u want u save data of four month in different objective in dictionary u generate dynamic key according to old key like images after that current time

Answer (score 4):

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName
                                  namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI
                                 qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
```

{

```
if ([elementName isEqualToString:"<image>"])
        {
            [imagearray addObject:imageurl];

        }
```

}

Before this you need to find the element name is  and then do above code.This may help you.

Comment: but where to init the image array?

Comment: You may take it in initWithData: method.Means when you pass your request.

Answer (score 1):

1. take dictionary in initWithData: methode
2. Take values as key like title, description
3. in didStartElement method, in images tag alloc image_array
4. in didEndElement method, in image tag add your data(here your image link) to image_array
5. now in didEndElement method, in images tag add that array to your main dictionary as key images

that's all.....